# Checking if an image field has changed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, blob

We have a database where the images are stored as image column types in a table. Periodically, we want to fire off a process that goes and checks to see if the images have been updated.

The process would:

1. Download the file from the source over HTTP
2. Check if the file is different from the db version
3. Update the db if necessary

I am not sure how to go about the second step. How would I check to see if the files are different?

EDIT:

How accurate would checking the image's size using `DATALENGTH` ?

Comment: Have you tried hashing the two images?  In SQL Server you ought to be able to use [HashBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(v=sql.100).aspx) to process blocks of up to 8000 bytes.  You could add a CLR function to handle an image in one swell foop and ensure that you are using the same hashing on both images.

Comment: @HABO: Unfortunately the images are significantly larger than 8000 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the file as `byte[]` array
2. Retrieve the `DATALENGTH` of the BLOB field from the SQL server:

   - `SELECT DATALENGTH(Content) AS ItemLength ...`
3. Compare the two. If they are equal, then they are the same image:

   - `byte[].Length` == BlobLength (`long`)